# Add a custom view on Secure text in UITextField and able to delete it

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am working on a login screen that takes a 4 digit pin. I have four different text field to take the pin input. I am trying to display the user entered digit by showing some star icons. I am presenting a star by adding a subView inside UITextView when the user enters a digit.

I can take all four digit input. Now I want to add a capability to press backspace so that previously entered digit gets removed. I cannot find a way to do this. Can anybody help me.

Some stack overflow solution suggests checking the string in shouldCheckCharactersInRange. But to detect the backspace you need to return true from the function. If we do this then the star is presented along with the pressed digit.

```
import UIKit

class PinSetupViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupNavbar()
        setupViews();

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1);

        firstPinTextView.delegate = self;
        secondPinTextView.delegate = self;
        thirdPinTextView.delegate = self;
        fourthPinTextView.delegate = self;
    }

    enum pinLabelFrame: Int {
        case height = 54, width = 50;
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let  char = string.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")

        if (isBackSpace == -92) {
            print("Backspace was pressed")
        }


        switch textField {
        case firstPinTextView:
            let star = Star(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pinLabelFrame.width.rawValue, height: pinLabelFrame.height.rawValue))
            firstPinTextView.addSubview(star);
            secondPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
            break;
        case secondPinTextView:
            let star = Star(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pinLabelFrame.width.rawValue, height: pinLabelFrame.height.rawValue))
            secondPinTextView.addSubview(star);
            thirdPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
            break;
        case thirdPinTextView:
            let star = Star(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pinLabelFrame.width.rawValue, height: pinLabelFrame.height.rawValue))
            thirdPinTextView.addSubview(star);
            fourthPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
        case fourthPinTextView:
            let star = Star(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pinLabelFrame.width.rawValue, height: pinLabelFrame.height.rawValue))
            fourthPinTextView.addSubview(star);
            thirdPinTextView.resignFirstResponder();
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }


    func setupNavbar(){
        navigationItem.title = "Set a PIN" // set title of navigation bar
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)]; //Change the font from bold to normal
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white; //set navigation bar background color to white

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil);
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .black;
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Skip", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(showConfirmPIN));
    }

    @objc func showConfirmPIN(){
        topTextView.text = "Confirm PIN."
        self.dismiss(animated: false) {
            self.present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: PinSetupViewController()), animated: false, completion: nil);
        }
    }

    func setupViews(){

        view.addSubview(topView);
        view.addSubview(topTextView);
        view.addSubview(pinContainerView);
        view.addSubview(bottomTextView);

        topView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true;
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true;
        topView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true;
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10).isActive = true;

        topTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
        topTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true;
        topTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true;
        topTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;

        pinContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
        pinContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTextView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true;
        pinContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.6).isActive = true;
        pinContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 54).isActive = true;

        setupPinsView();

        bottomTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
        bottomTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true;
        bottomTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true;
        bottomTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 130).isActive = true;
    }

    func setupPinsView(){
        pinContainerView.addSubview(firstPinTextView);
        pinContainerView.addSubview(secondPinTextView);
        pinContainerView.addSubview(thirdPinTextView);
        pinContainerView.addSubview(fourthPinTextView);

        firstPinTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true;
        firstPinTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        firstPinTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        firstPinTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;

        secondPinTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstPinTextView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
        secondPinTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        secondPinTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        secondPinTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;

        thirdPinTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondPinTextView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
        thirdPinTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        thirdPinTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        thirdPinTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;

        fourthPinTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: thirdPinTextView.rightAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true;
        fourthPinTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true;
        fourthPinTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pinContainerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true;
        fourthPinTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true;
    }

    let topView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView();
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return view;
    }();

    let pinContainerView : UIView = {
        let view = UIView();
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return view;
    }();
    let topTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView();
        tv.textAlignment = .center
        tv.text = "Set a PIN for quicker mobile \n banking access.";
        tv.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14);
        tv.backgroundColor = .clear;
        tv.isEditable = false;
        tv.isSelectable = false;
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tv;
    }();

    let firstPinTextView : UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField();
        tf.backgroundColor = .black;
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad;
        tf.textAlignment = .center;
        tf.textColor = UIColor.white;
        tf.tintColor = .clear;
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40);
        tf.becomeFirstResponder();
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tf;
    }();

    let secondPinTextView : UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField();
        tf.backgroundColor = .black;
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad;
        tf.textAlignment = .center;
        tf.textColor = UIColor.white;
        tf.tintColor = .clear;
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18);
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tf;
    }();

    let thirdPinTextView : UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField();
        tf.backgroundColor = .black;
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad;
        tf.textAlignment = .center;
        tf.textColor = UIColor.white;
        tf.tintColor = .clear;
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18);
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tf;
    }();

    let fourthPinTextView : UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField();
        tf.backgroundColor = .black;
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad;
        tf.textAlignment = .center;
        tf.textColor = UIColor.white;
        tf.tintColor = .clear;
        tf.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18);
        tf.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tf;
    }();

    let bottomTextView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView();
        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "If you'd prefer to use your NetBank password to log \n on instead of a PIN, simply skip this step. \n\n Don't choose a PIN that can be easily guessed (e.g. \n you birthday or name). If you do, you may liable \n for unauthorized transactions. \n\n This PIN will apply wherever you access mobile \n banking (excluding CommSec and CommBiz apps). ", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)]);

        tv.attributedText = attributedText;
        tv.textAlignment = .center
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        tv.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark;
        tv.isEditable = false;
        tv.isSelectable = false;
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        return tv;
    }();
}
```

//----------------- Answer ---------------------//

```
//Add this function to your text field target
    @objc func showSecurePassword(_ textField: UITextField){
        guard let  char = textField.text?.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else{
            return
        }
        let isBackSpace = strcmp(char, "\\b")
        pins.newPin += textField.text!

        switch textField{
        case firstPinTextField:
            if !(isBackSpace == -92){
                //Valid digit entered i.e 0 - 9
                addViewToTextField(firstPinTextField, secureView.star1);
            }else{
                //Backspace detected ...
                removerSubviewFromTextField(secureView.star1);
                pins.newPin = String(pins.newPin.dropLast()) //Remove the last element from the 4 digit pin
                firstPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }

        case secondPinTextField:
            if !(isBackSpace == -92){
                addViewToTextField(secondPinTextField, secureView.star2);
            }else{
                removerSubviewFromTextField(secureView.star2);
                pins.newPin = String(pins.newPin.dropLast()) //Remove the last element from the 4 digit pin
                firstPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }
        case thirdPinTextField:
            if !(isBackSpace == -92){
                addViewToTextField(thirdPinTextField, secureView.star3);
            }else{
                removerSubviewFromTextField(secureView.star3);
                pins.newPin = String(pins.newPin.dropLast()) //Remove the last element from the 4 digit pin
                secondPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }
        case fourthPinTextField:
            if !(isBackSpace == -92){
                addViewToTextField(fourthPinTextField, secureView.star4);
                if((!pins.oldPin.isEmpty) && (pins.oldPin == pins.newPin)){
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                        self.resetAllTextFields();
                        self.removeAllSubViewsFromTextField();
                        self.showTermsAndConditionViewController();
                    })

                }else if ((!pins.newPin.isEmpty && !pins.oldPin.isEmpty) && pins.oldPin != pins.newPin){
                    pins.newPin = ""; //Reset both pins
                    pins.oldPin = "";
                    resetAllTextFields(); //Resest all text fields
                    removeAllSubViewsFromTextField() //Remove all the views from text Fields
                    vibratePhone(); //Vibrate phone
                }
                else{
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
                        self.promtForReenteringPassword();
                    })
                }

            }else{
                removerSubviewFromTextField(secureView.star4);
                pins.newPin = String(pins.newPin.dropLast()) //Remove the last element from the 4 digit pin
                thirdPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();

            }
        default:
            break;
        }
        print("Old pin is \(pins.oldPin)");
        print("New pin is \(pins.newPin)");
    }


// Function to limit the number of characters in a text field so that the focus remains within itself when first character is entered and goes to other text field when more than one character gets entered
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        switch textField {
        case firstPinTextField:
            if !isNumberOfCharsWithinDefinedValue(firstPinTextField, string: string){
                firstPinTextField.text = getTextToSetTheTextField(firstPinTextField, string: string)
                secondPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }
        case secondPinTextField:
            if !isNumberOfCharsWithinDefinedValue(secondPinTextField, string: string){
                secondPinTextField.text = getTextToSetTheTextField(secondPinTextField, string: string)
                thirdPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }
        case thirdPinTextField:
            if !isNumberOfCharsWithinDefinedValue(thirdPinTextField, string: string){
                thirdPinTextField.text = getTextToSetTheTextField(thirdPinTextField, string: string)
                fourthPinTextField.becomeFirstResponder();
            }
        case fourthPinTextField:
            if !isNumberOfCharsWithinDefinedValue(fourthPinTextField, string: string){
                fourthPinTextField.text = getTextToSetTheTextField(fourthPinTextField, string: string)
                return false
            }
        default:
            break
        }

        return true;
    }

 //Check number of characters within the given text field. If number of characters exceeds the limit then return false else return true;
    func isNumberOfCharsWithinDefinedValue(_ textField: UITextField, string: String) -> Bool{
        if let text = textField.text  {
            let str = text + string;

            if str.count <= constant.TEXT_FIELD_MAX_CHAR{
                return true
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    func removerSubviewFromTextField(_ textView: UIView){
        if let tv = textView.viewWithTag(100){
            tv.removeFromSuperview();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using `NSTextAttachment` adding your stars as NSTextAttachment maybe can help you and reduce unnecessary work and code

Comment: how can we use NSTextAttachment to display a star

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this inside the textField delegate function:

```
if string.characters.count == 0 && range.length > 0 {
  // Back pressed
  switch textField {
  case secondPinTextView:
      clearTextView(firstPinTextView);
      firstPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
      break;
  case thirdPinTextView:
      clearTextView(secondPinTextView);
      secondPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
      break;
  case fourthPinTextView:
      clearTextView(thirdPinTextView);
      thirdPinTextView.becomeFirstResponder();
      break;
  default:
      break;
}
```

Add this attribute to your star definition:

```
testView.tag = 100
```

And create this function:

```
func clearTextView(textView: UITextView){
  if let viewWithTag = textView.viewWithTag(100) {
    textView.text = "";
    viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? As it need return true on the delegate function to detect the backspace.

Comment: Its working fine when you return True in the delegate function. But it overlaps the enterned number with the star view

Comment: Isn't the star view disappearing? The number should be cleared as well, let me edit. I don't fully understand what overlap is happening.

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?